# how to combine ng-if , ng-click and ng-show and use them together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***Pre-info***

I try to sperate Admin and customer in a different stage or view.

so that, admin can modify the table before releasing it to customers.

***Questions***
In the table -> *td* there is button to control the staging, release(show) or revert (hide)?

so basically what I wanna do is that every table checked can be shown on the both in admin and customer. if it's unchecked, the data only show to admin.

Currently, the code is disabled whole table-body instead of 1 row.

is there any way to check or uncheck only 1 row?

thanks for the advice.

```js
 $scope.showDiv = isAdmin();


        $scope.toggleShowDiv = function () {


            $scope.showDiv = !isAdmin()&isAdmin();
            console.log('fired');


        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 80px">foo1</th>
    <th style="width: 80px">foo2</th>
    <th style="width: 200px">foo3</th>
    <th>foo4</th>
    <th>foo5</th>
    <th>foo6</th>



  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="auction-group" ng-repeat="a in foos" ng-if="showDiv">
  <tr>
    <td>abcd1</td>
    <td>abcd1</td>
    <td>abcd1</td>
    <td>abcd3</td>

    <td>abcd4</td>
    <td>abcd5</td>

    //is admin - show only to admin
    <td ng-if="::isAdmin()">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleShowDiv()" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your first ng-if outside ng-repeat

```
<div ng-if="showDiv">
   <tbody class="auction-group" ng-repeat="a in foos">
</div>
```

second ng-if should be like this,

```
<td ng-if="isAdmin()">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleShowDiv()" />
</td>
```

Comment: what should I do if I just wanna disable one row?

Comment: and my !isAdmin () is not passing thru showDiv  after the click ? any suggestion?